# How to loop through elements from a python pandas dataframe to a new nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am currently using pandas library to read data from a CSV file. The data includes a "data" column which consists of 1's and 0's, and a "published_at" column which has unique time and date stamps (I have converted it to become the index of the dataframe).
[Click here to see picture of the Dataframe from CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yznc2.png) (I deleted the core_id data as it is irrelevant).

In the data, a "1" means yes and "0" means no. I would like to analyze the data by looping through the dataframe from a certain start date to an end date (i.e. 2020-11-26 to 2020-11-27) and count how many times "1" (yes_data) occurred, and how many times "0" (no_data) occurred in each day. And from there, I would like to create a new CSV file or dataframe that contains that data so I can analyze it from there.

The way I tried to approach this is by creating a nested dictionary and trying to populate it by looping through the main dataframe and counting how many times "yes" and "no" occurred per day.

I would like to end up with a dictionary (or dataframe, csv file, whatever..) that has 3 columns: date (i.e. 2020-11-26), "yes" count, and "no" count.

Below is the code I came up with:

```
yes_data = 0
no_data = 0
date_id = '2020-11-26'

# Create a dictionary to populate a new dataframe
#new_data = {
#  date_id: {'yes': yes_data, 'no': no_data},
#  "2020-11-27": {'yes': 2, 'no': 2}}
new_data = {"":{}}

# I tried to convert the csv data to a dictionary but I don't know
# if this is necessary so I commented it out
# csv_dict = csv_data.to_dict

csv_dict = csv_data

for day in csv_dict['2020-11-26':'2020-11-27']:
    new_data[day] = csv_dict[day]
    for state in csv_dict['2020-11-26':'2020-11-27'].data:
        if state == 1:
            yes_data += 1
            new_data[day][state] == yes_data
        elif state == 0:
            no_data += 1
            new_data[day][state] == no_data
```

However the code does not work (I keep getting errors everywhere..). How can I fix it to do what I'm trying to do? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. I'm fairly new to Python, trying my best here!

Comment: What is the error(s) you are getting? Can you provide a minimal example? (also, try to avoid loops on dataframes. If you want to count values in a series use `.value_counts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you're doing well.
This snippet will help you do the job!

```
result = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows(): # Iterates over the row
    date = row['published_at'].split(' ')[0]  # This line takes only the date of the row ( not hour and minute ...)
    ans = row['data']  # Finds if the data is zero or one
    if date not in result:  # Creates an entery for this date if it hasn't created yet
        result[date] = {'yes':0, 'no':0}
    if ans: # Increases the number of yes if ans == 1
        result[date]['yes']+=1 
    else:  # Increases the number of yes if ans == 0
        result[date]['no'] +=1
```

Keep in mind that *df* is your data frame and row['data'] means the 0 or 1. So if you have different names, change it.
At the end of this code, you're gonna have a dictionary with the structure as mentions in the following.

```
result = {'2020-12-01': {'yes': 2, 'no': 4}, '2020-12-4': {'yes':n, 'no':m} }
```

Have a good day

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! I adjusted it to fit my needs a bit more by creating a new column csv_data['date'] and copying over the csv_data.index.date. Doing so allowed me to remove the .split('  ')[0] from the date variable, which was giving me errors for some reason.

The rest worked like a charm! Thanks again

Comment: @encrypted_shadow. You're welcome! Happy coding :D